# Muslim Girl Commit sins

Tags: sex

I am A Muslim Girl.  I never did sexual things in life, I am single. Once my colleague (Muslim Boy) offered me a coffee, In the car, he forced me to suck his dick and threaten me. I was afraid if he will do something wrong with me, I sucked his dick for a few minutes and he sucked my breasts. I am very tensed. Kindly tell me if Toba can purify me? my intentions were never bad? I am very worried and I left doing Ibadah, plz guide me.

Comment: You should have told this your parents and the authorities this is a crime and you didn't commit any sin if you were forced to do it.

Comment: @Sassir Perhaps she is in a society where women would get blamed for losing their "purity" even if they were forced. Sadly, it is very common.

Comment: Why were you doing hanging with a pervert boy and alone with him in the car, you should know better.

Answer (score 2):

"In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful."

Assalamu Alaikum,
My Dear Sister, Allah S.W.T is merciful and forgiving. First of all don't be in contact with non mahram. When a boy and girl is alone then the third one is Shaytan. 
it is said that when a person feels unhappy about the sin, it is the sign of a believer. You can see, there is true repentance at the end of verse.True repentance means that you should use that unhappiness in your heart a sign of repentance.
Secondly, It's a Crime he did Try talking about to your parents and police(Only if you are fine with it). And stay away from that molester. Please Do Recitation daily, Do Namaz of 5 times, and Do Astagfar. Ask for sincere repentance and Inshallah You'll Be Forgiven. Form next time onwards please don't be alone with a non mahram and avoid bad friend circle. Also,

May Allah Forgive You.
Allah Hafiz